# How to expand an HTML webpage when collapsing an accordion panel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In my webpage I have accordion panels which collapse and close. I have set the page height to be specific.  However, I want it to be specific from the start, but be able to expand when I open and close the panel, so that I don't have to set the page too be so long with no content. Any ideas about how I go about doing this?

This is only an example I used, which is the reason for the small height currently.

My Current Code:

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <title>London Tour Guide</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

        <script src="jquery.js"></script>

        <style>
            div.container { position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 400px; width: 720px; height: 1300px;
                background-color: white; }

            div.content {
                width: 700px; height: 120px;
                background-color: lightblue; padding: 5px; }

            button.accordion {
                background-color: #eee;
                color: #444;
                cursor: pointer;
                padding: 18px;
                width: 100%;
                border: none;
                text-align: left;
                outline: none;
                font-size: 15px;
                transition: 0.4s;
            }

            button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
                background-color: #ddd;
            }

            div.panel {
                padding: 0 18px;
                display: none;
                background-color: white;
            }

            div.panel.show {
                display: block;
            }




        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class = "content">


            <button class="accordion">Panel</button>
            <div class="panel">
                Hello
            </div>
            <button class="accordion">Panel 2</button>
            <div class="panel">
                Hello
            </div>

            <script>
                var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
                var i;

                for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
                    acc[i].onclick = function(){
                        this.classList.toggle("active");
                        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
                    }
                }
            </script>

        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly,

you're looking for `min-height:1300px` instead of `height:1300px` on `div.container`

Comment: Why would that be the case tho? if all my data is held within the content page wouldnt that be that page which exists? or would it still be the container

Answer (score 0):

The most robust way without the use of Javascript is to get rid of explicitly setting the height of your containers in CSS - that way the height is automatically going to conform to the total height of your child elements.

If your container is not absolutely positioned, I believe Vlad is Glad's answer with using the CSS property, min-height, will apply.

If your container must be absolutely positioned, you could grab the height of the expanded panel through jQuery in your onClick handler, and add/subtract the height to your container.

Comment: But dont we want the content to expand not the container?

Comment: You can do the same height additions/subtractions to the div.content. Or do you even need to set an explicit height for div.content? Your main concern was page height right?